# How can I call websocket apigateway from a lambda with vpc configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-vpc

I have deployed a public websocket api gateway in AWS and my lambda needs to call `PostToConnection" on the apigateway to response message to clients. It works fine if the lambda is running without any VPC configuration.

However, when I configure a private or public subnet on the lambda, I will receive

`operation error ApiGatewayManagementApi: PostToConnection, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 9ba9758d-b812-4f37-99d2-7f30782a8b64, ForbiddenException:`

error message.

THe lambda uses the `https://` endpoint on the websocket apigateway.

How can I let the vpc lambda call PosToConnection on a public websocket apigateway?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda when placed in a public subnet won't have internet access, since public IP addresses are not assigned to Lambda. For Lambda to have internet access when placed in a VPC, you need a private subnet with NAT instance or NAT Gateway for internet access. Also,  the security group needs to allow the outbound traffic.